# Handle exception raised in task

Tags: elixir

I have some code I would like to run in a task but it may throw an error. I have tried wrapping in a try/rescue however the error is not caught.

```
try do
    Supervisor.start_link([ {Task, fn -> raise "kaboom" end}], strategy:  :one_for_one)
rescue
    RuntimeError -> "Error!"
end
```

I was hoping for "Error!" to be printed however i get -

```
(RuntimeError) kaboom
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:678: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
(elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:90: Task.Supervised.invoke_mfa/2
(stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: #Function<20.128620087/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
Args: []
{:ok, #PID<0.332.0>}
```

Is there any way to handle exceptions raised inside of a task from it's instigator?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[`Task`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Task.html) is started as a separated process. The intercommunication of two processes can only be exchanging messages. One cannot expect to `rescue` anything happened in one process from another process—processes are *isolated*.

One might `rescue` inside a callee process (a task itself,) or simply start a task as `:transient` and check the outcome, but this is an attempt to reinvent a functionality already provided by OTP.

Check [linking](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Task.html#async/3-linking) chapter in the documentation.

If all you want would be to retry on occasional exception raised, start the task supervised and let it raise and crash, OTP will take care of everything else, including restarts, etc.

If you need to try once and react somehow on the exception raised, you probably should reconsider the architecture and start the monitored process instead, trapping exits.

Comment: Thanks Aleksei, I am just starting to learn about processes, tasks etc - and haven't been taking into consideration the facts in your first sentence. Your answer has given me a great starting point for learning how these things should actually be used.